# Bypass Button IsDefault 

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, keyboard-events

I have a button in my form...

```
<Button Name="Submit" Content="OK"
                IsDefault="True"
                Click="Submit_Click"/>
```

You sure know, what it does. What i need, is to bypass the submit event while hitting Enter, but only in one field of all in my form...

```
<TextBox Name="ArticleBarcode"
             Text="{Binding Path=Barcode}"
             KeyDown="ArticleBarcode_KeyDown"/>
```

The reason, why do I need such a thing, is because the input of the barcode is going to be set via barcode reader. User reads an article barcode with his reader and it works like wireless keyboard. It sends keystrokes - numbers of the barcode and at the end, it sends Enter keystroke. So I need to get this enter keystroke and cancel the submit, if it comes from that particular field. How can I do that?

Thanks, JiKra

Comment: If you make handled = true then it still fires the Submit?

Comment: Did you try the PreviewKeyDown event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by others:

In the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the TextBox, set `e.Handled` to True if the key pressed has been the `Enter` key:

```
private void ArticleBarcode_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

This prevents the key from triggering other handlers, such as the one responsible for executing the default button.